# Подключение dll

Tags: java, dll

Доброго времени суток! Я написал апплет и упаковал его в jar. В ту же папку положил все dll библиотеки, которые требуются. Но при запуске в браузере апплет выдает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-15" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\dmitriy.nikolaev\AppData\Local\Temp\javacpp3225777614302\jniopencv_core.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Получается, библиотеки не ищутся в той же папке, что и апплет? Что делать?

Comment: Содержимое тега <applet> в студию!

Comment: <applet 
archive="camera.jar, opencv-245.jar, javacv.jar, javacpp.jar, ffmpeg-1.2-windows-x86_64.jar, javacv-windows-x86_64.jar"
 
width="640" 
height="600" 
code="ReviewApplet2.class">
<h1>nu ept</h1>
</applet>

Answer (score 2):

DLL видимо у вас грузится через `System.loadLibrary()` а раз так то варианты такие:

1. Указать в исходнике полный путь на DLL, но это  плохой вариант, поскольку апплет штука сетевая то что такое полный путь в сети - это ни о чем. В варианте запуска из localhost сработает а вот из сети не будет
2. Указать путь относительно параметра `codebase` и выложить DLL на сервере относительно корня сервера
3. Если путь не указан, то библиотека будет искаться в PATH сервера - ИМХО это самый простой вариант.
4. Можно указать CLASSPATH апплета типа:

   <resources os="Windows" arch="x86">
      <nativelib href="lib/mylib.dll"/>
   </resources>

Comment: не помогло, пришлось кинуть все либы в win32